# jquery get value in brackets using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This has probably been asked a million times, and i am probably way off in what i have below, but i can not find it anywhere on SO.  I need to get my alert below to show the value inside the brackets.

```
//the element(thisId) holds the following string:   id[33]     
var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
var idNum = new RegExp("\[(.*?)\]");
alert(idNum);
```

I need the alert to show the value `33`.

Comment: Well you do not use the regular expression...Of course it will not show the value.

Comment: thats what i saw too.  I just dont know what to do with it....

Comment: Learn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: if it always has id[someIndex], why not simply `thisId .replace('id[', '').replace(']', '');`

Answer (score 2):

You need to match the string with the regular expression, not just create the regexp. This returns an array containing the full match and the matches for capture groups.

```js
var thisId = 'id[33]';
var match = thisId.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
alert(match[1]); // Show first capture
```

Comment: this returns "id[33".

Comment: It alerts `33` for me.

Comment: I had a typo in my first version of the answer, but I fixed it when I changed to the Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec()` to get the matches to your Regex:

```
var thisId = 'id[33]';
var matches = /\[(.*?)\]/g.exec(thisId);
alert(matches[1]); // you want the first group captured
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ewyo99nm/)